# How to add tickmarks to polar axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, radar-chart, multiple-axes

Could you help me add tickmarks to each of the axes in my polar plot below?

Here is an image of a polar plot with the tickmarks I want on the axes: http://blog.scottlogic.com/archive/2011/09/few.png

This is an image of my current plot without tickmarks on the axes:

[image: Current Plot]

This is the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as py

class Radar(object):

def __init__(self, fig, titles, labels, rect=None):
    if rect is None:
        rect = [0.05, 0.05, 0.95, 0.95]

    self.n = len(titles)
    self.angles = [a if a <=360. else a - 360. for a in np.arange(90, 90+360, 360.0/self.n)]
    self.axes = [fig.add_axes(rect, projection="polar", label="axes%d" % i) 
                     for i in range(self.n)]

    self.ax = self.axes[0]
    self.ax.set_thetagrids(self.angles, labels=titles, 
                           fontsize=13, weight="normal", color="black")

    for ax in self.axes[1:]:
        ax.patch.set_visible(False)
        ax.grid("off")
        ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        self.ax.yaxis.grid(False)

    for ax, angle, label in zip(self.axes, self.angles, labels):
        ax.set_rgrids(range(1, 7), labels=label, angle=angle, fontsize=12)
        ax.spines["polar"].set_visible(False)
        ax.set_ylim(0, 6)  
        ax.xaxis.grid(True,color='black',linestyle='-')
        pos=ax.get_rlabel_position()
        ax.set_rlabel_position(pos+3)

def plot(self, values, *args, **kw):
    angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[self.angles, self.angles[0]])
    values = np.r_[values, values[0]]
    self.ax.plot(angle, values, *args, **kw)

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

titles = [
"Canada", "Australia", "New\nZealand", "Japan", 
"China", "USA", "Mexico", "Finland", "Doha" 
]

labels = [
list("abcde"), list("12345"), list("uvwxy"), 
[" ", " ", "$156", "$158", "$160"],
list("jklmn"), list("asdfg"), list("qwert"), 
[" ", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5", "4.6"], list("abcde")
]

radar = Radar(fig, titles, labels)
radar.plot([1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 2],  "--", lw=1, color="b", alpha=.5, label="USA 2014")
radar.plot([2.3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2],"-", lw=1, color="r", alpha=.5, label="2014")
radar.plot([3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2], "-", lw=1, color="g", alpha=.5, label="2013")
radar.plot([4.5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], "-", lw=1, color="y", alpha=.5, label="2012")

radar.ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.10),
      fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)

py.text(0.5, 1.15, "Seattle, WA\n", weight="bold", fontsize=22,
    transform=py.gca().transAxes, ha='center')
py.text(0.5, 1.15, "Market Data from 2012 to 2014", fontsize=14,
    transform=py.gca().transAxes, ha='center')

fig = py.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(6, 10, forward=True)
fig.savefig('test2png.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add tickmarks to polar plot Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139489/how-to-add-tickmarks-to-polar-plot-matplotlib)

Comment: @HayleyGuillou Just trying to get some fresh eyes on this and find some help

Comment: For the future: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: Thanks! @HayleyGuillou I just deleted my original duplicate posts that got no action